# Submit function after Confirm popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, submit, confirm

I would like to have a confirmation popup, where i can use "ok" or "cancel" before the event is submitted, but i can't managed it.

Here is my code, thanks for your help!

```
$('#display_events_form').submit(function() {
            var data="eventid="+eventid+"&person="+globe_search_general_person;

            $.post('join_event.php', data,  function(response){

                  $.each(response, function(index) {

                      $('<p align="left">Eventname: ' + response[index].name +
                        '<br>Datum / Uhrzeit: ' + response[index].startdate +
                        '<br>Ersparnis: ' + response[index].saving + ' EUR'+
                        '<br>Treffpunkt: ' + response[index].meetingpoint + '</p>')
                        .appendTo("#join_event_response_event_details");

                        //display_events_form
                    });

            },'json');

            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#join_event_response", {transition: "slide"});
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3791330, before `$.post()` you can put following code to work as you want

```
if(!confirm("__YOUR MSG GOES HERE____")){
   return false; 
}
```

or you can test like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!confirm("Are you sure to countinue ?")){
        return false;
    }
    alert("Hi,I m on the way !!");    
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you the first one works perfect. Is it possible to style the popup? Don't want to have the internet address as a headline.

Comment: You can't add style to javascript popup (confirm()). You should use  jquery model or other model plugins..

Comment: How do I have to change the code if i use a jquery mobile plugin?